# Monotonicity of an elementary function

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

I'd like to prove that the function:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(\sin x)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$, with $f(0)$ understood in the limiting sense.

Computing the derivative reduces the problem to showing that
$$
(\sin x)^3-x^3 \cos x \ge 0, \qquad x\in [0,\pi/2],
$$
but I don't know how to handle it. Any hints will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks a bunch :]

Comment: There are better ways to prove that.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Feel free to share, it'd be nice to see your approach.

Comment: $$\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac1{x^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{2^{2n}\,\cos^2\frac{x}{2^n}}$$

Comment: Wow, it looks cool! Could you quickly sketch how does one prove such an identity?

Comment: $$\frac1{\sin^2x}=\frac1{4\,\sin^2\frac{x}2\,\cos^2\frac{x}2}=\frac1{4\,\sin^2\frac{x}2}+\frac1{4\,\cos^2\frac{x}2}$$

Comment: Gotcha! That's really cute. Thanks a lot!